# Why I get additional error message by Node.js for my code with try/catch?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I use try/catch block inside of async function but I get some additional error message by Node.js. My code:

```
const work = count => {
    const promise = new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
        const interval = setInterval(() => {
            console.log(count--);
            if(!count){
                try{
                    clearInterval(interval);
                    throw 'Oops...'; // emulate unexpected error...
                    resolve('Work done!');
                }
                catch(err){
                    reject(err);
                }
            }
        }, 1000);
        console.log('Bingo!');
    });
    return promise;
};

const promise = work(3);
promise.then(context => console.log(`Ressult: ${context}`));
promise.catch(err => console.log(`Error: ${err}`));
```

Result:

[image]

What I did wrong?

Comment: you're not handling the potential error returned here `.then(context => console.log(\`Ressult: ${context}\`));` (hint: `.then` returns a new promise)

Comment: @George yes, thank you!

Comment: So @George - that would be a *duplicate* :p

Comment: @Bravo That's what SO generates as a comment when you VTC as a duplicate now

Comment: ahh, OK @George - :p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to update your code like below: You didn't handle rejected promise as `.then` returns new promise which is errored promise in your case.

```
    const work = count => {
    const promise = new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
        const interval = setInterval(() => {
            console.log(count--);
            if(!count){
                try{
                    clearInterval(interval);
                    throw 'Oops...'; // emulate unexpected error...
                    resolve('Work done!');
                }
                catch(err){
                    reject(err);
                }
            }
        }, 1000);
        console.log('Bingo!');
    });
    return promise;
};
const promise = work(3);
promise.then(context => console.log(`Ressult: ${context}`)).catch(err => console.log(`Error: ${err}`));
```